# Internationalization for programmatically created strings

Tags: ios, swift

Could anyone help me how to internationalize string created programmatically? I have this simple method creating alert.

```
func loginAlert(viewController : UIViewController , callback: (result: Bool) -> ()) {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title : "Login Required",
            message : "Please enter your username and password",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert
        )

        var service = Service()

        var loginAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){
            UIAlertAction in

        }
        var cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel){
            UIAlertAction in

        }

        alert.addAction(loginAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Username"
        }

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
            textField.secureTextEntry = true
            textField.placeholder = "Password"

        }


        viewController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

I would like to make some string like "Login Required", "Please enter your username and password", etc. to be internationalized.

The way I did it for the non programmatically created string is by this tutorial [here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/). The way that tutorial did is just some works in project setting.

Could anyone help me what is usual way and correct way of doing it?

Comment: Check the section "Localizing Dynamic Strings" in the tutorial. Read the code carefully. When you say "the way that tutorial did is just some works in project settings", that's obviously wrong once you read it carefully.

Comment: You seem to be confused where you chose a language: You don't. The user does that. You just supply all the languages you want to supply. If you supply German, French, Italian then everyone with their phone set to German sees the German text, everyone with their phone set to French sees the French text and so on. If a language isn't supported, the first supported language is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle` equivalent. See the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html)